# Does sbf() use metric argument to optimize model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret, rfe

Passing `ROC` as `metric` argument value to the `caretSBF` function

Our objective is to use the ROC summary metric for model selection while running the Selection By Filtering `sbf()` function for features selection.

The `BreastCancer` dataset was used as a reproducible example from `mlbench` package to run `train()` and `sbf()` with `metric = "Accuracy"` and `metric = "ROC"`

We want to make sure `sbf()` takes the `metric` argument as applied by the `train()` and `rfe()` functions to optimize the model. To this aim, we planned to make use of the `train()` function with the `sbf()` function.  The `caretSBF$fit` function makes a call to `train()`, and `caretSBF` is passed to `sbfControl`.

From the output, it seems the `metric` argument is used just for `inner resampling` and not for the `sbf` part, i.e. for the `outer resampling` of the output, the `metric` argument was not applied as used by `train()` and `rfe()`.

As we have used `caretSBF` which uses `train()`, it appears that the `metric` argument is limited in scope to `train()` and hence is not passed to `sbf`.

We would appreciate clarification on whether `sbf()` uses `metric` argument for optimizing model, i.e. for `outer resampling`?

Here is our work on reproducible example, showing `train()` uses `metric` argument using `Accuracy` and `ROC`, but for `sbf` we are not sure.

**I. DATA SECTION**

```
  ## Loading required packages   
  library(mlbench)
  library(caret)

  ## Loading `BreastCancer` Dataset from *mlbench* package   
  data("BreastCancer")

  ## Data cleaning for missing values
  # Remove rows/observation with NA Values in any of the columns
  BrC1 <- BreastCancer[complete.cases(BreastCancer),] 

  # Removing Class and Id Column and keeping just Numeric Predictors
  Num_Pred <- BrC1[,2:10]
```

**II. CUSTOMIZED SUMMARY FUNCTION**

**Defining fiveStats summary function**

```
  fiveStats <- function(...) c(twoClassSummary(...),
                         defaultSummary(...))
```

**III. TRAIN SECTION**

**Defining trControl**

```
  trCtrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10,
  repeats=1, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = fiveStats)
```

**TRAIN + METRIC = "Accuracy"**

```
   set.seed(1)
   TR_acc <- train(Num_Pred,BrC1$Class, method="rf",metric="Accuracy",
   trControl = trCtrl,tuneGrid=expand.grid(.mtry=c(2,3,4,5)))

   TR_acc
   # Random Forest 
   # 
   # 683 samples
   #   9 predictor
   #   2 classes: 'benign', 'malignant' 
   # 
   # No pre-processing
   # Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # Summary of sample sizes: 615, 615, 614, 614, 614, 615, ... 
   # Resampling results across tuning parameters:
   # 
   #   mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec       Accuracy   Kappa    
   #   2     0.9936532  0.9729798  0.9833333  0.9765772  0.9490311
   #   3     0.9936544  0.9729293  0.9791667  0.9750853  0.9457534
   #   4     0.9929957  0.9684343  0.9750000  0.9706948  0.9361373
   #   5     0.9922907  0.9684343  0.9666667  0.9677536  0.9295782
   # 
   # Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
   # The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

**TRAIN + METRIC = "ROC"**

```
   set.seed(1)
   TR_roc <- train(Num_Pred,BrC1$Class, method="rf",metric="ROC",
   trControl = trCtrl,tuneGrid=expand.grid(.mtry=c(2,3,4,5)))
   TR_roc
   # Random Forest 
   # 
   # 683 samples
   #   9 predictor
   #   2 classes: 'benign', 'malignant' 
   # 
   # No pre-processing
   # Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # Summary of sample sizes: 615, 615, 614, 614, 614, 615, ... 
   # Resampling results across tuning parameters:
   # 
   #   mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec       Accuracy   Kappa    
   #   2     0.9936532  0.9729798  0.9833333  0.9765772  0.9490311
   #   3     0.9936544  0.9729293  0.9791667  0.9750853  0.9457534
   #   4     0.9929957  0.9684343  0.9750000  0.9706948  0.9361373
   #   5     0.9922907  0.9684343  0.9666667  0.9677536  0.9295782
   # 
   # ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
   # The final value used for the model was mtry = 3.
```

**IV. EDITING caretSBF**

**Editing caretSBF summary Function**

```
   caretSBF$summary <- fiveStats
```

**V. SBF SECTION**

**Defining sbfControl**

```
   sbfCtrl <- sbfControl(functions=caretSBF, 
   method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=1,
   verbose=T, saveDetails = T)
```

**SBF + METRIC = "Accuracy"**

```
   set.seed(1)
   sbf_acc <- sbf(Num_Pred, BrC1$Class,
   sbfControl = sbfCtrl,
   trControl = trCtrl, method="rf", metric="Accuracy")

   ## sbf_acc  
   sbf_acc

   # Selection By Filter
   # 
   # Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # 
   # Resampling performance:
   # 
   #     ROC  Sens   Spec Accuracy Kappa    ROCSD SensSD  SpecSD AccuracySD  KappaSD
   #  0.9931 0.973 0.9833   0.9766 0.949 0.006272 0.0231 0.02913    0.01226 0.02646
   # 
   # Using the training set, 9 variables were selected:
   #    Cl.thickness, Cell.size, Cell.shape, Marg.adhesion, Epith.c.size...
   # 
   # During resampling, the top 5 selected variables (out of a possible 9):
   #    Bare.nuclei (100%), Bl.cromatin (100%), Cell.shape (100%), Cell.size (100%), Cl.thickness (100%)
   # 
   # On average, 9 variables were selected (min = 9, max = 9)

   ## Class of sbf_acc
   class(sbf_acc)
   # [1] "sbf"

   ## Names of elements of sbf_acc
   names(sbf_acc)
   #  [1] "pred"         "variables"    "results"      "fit"          "optVariables"
   #  [6] "call"         "control"      "resample"     "metrics"      "times"       
   # [11] "resampledCM"  "obsLevels"    "dots"        

   ## sbf_acc fit element*  
   sbf_acc$fit
   # Random Forest 
   # 
   # 683 samples
   #   9 predictor
   #   2 classes: 'benign', 'malignant' 
   # 
   # No pre-processing
   # Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # Summary of sample sizes: 615, 614, 614, 615, 615, 615, ... 
   # Resampling results across tuning parameters:
   # 
   #   mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec       Accuracy   Kappa    
   #   2     0.9933176  0.9706566  0.9833333  0.9751492  0.9460717
   #   5     0.9920034  0.9662121  0.9791667  0.9707801  0.9363708
   #   9     0.9914825  0.9684343  0.9708333  0.9693308  0.9327662
   # 
   # Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
   # The final value used for the model was mtry = 2. 

   ##  Elements of sbf_acc fit  
   names(sbf_acc$fit)
   #  [1] "method"       "modelInfo"    "modelType"    "results"      "pred"        
   #  [6] "bestTune"     "call"         "dots"         "metric"       "control"     
   # [11] "finalModel"   "preProcess"   "trainingData" "resample"     "resampledCM" 
   # [16] "perfNames"    "maximize"     "yLimits"      "times"        "levels"      

   ## sbf_acc fit final Model
   sbf_acc$fit$finalModel

   # Call:
   #  randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry) 
   #                Type of random forest: classification
   #                      Number of trees: 500
   # No. of variables tried at each split: 2
   # 
   #         OOB estimate of  error rate: 2.34%
   # Confusion matrix:
   #           benign malignant class.error
   # benign       431        13  0.02927928
   # malignant      3       236  0.01255230

   ## sbf_acc metric
   sbf_acc$fit$metric
   # [1] "Accuracy"

   ## sbf_acc fit best Tune*  
   sbf_acc$fit$bestTune
   #   mtry
   # 1    2
```

**SBF + METRIC = "ROC"**

```
   set.seed(1)
   sbf_roc <- sbf(Num_Pred, BrC1$Class,
   sbfControl = sbfCtrl,
   trControl = trCtrl, method="rf", metric="ROC")


   ## sbf_roc  
   sbf_roc

   # Selection By Filter
   # 
   # Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # 
   # Resampling performance:
   # 
   #     ROC  Sens   Spec Accuracy Kappa    ROCSD SensSD  SpecSD AccuracySD KappaSD
   #  0.9931 0.973 0.9833   0.9766 0.949 0.006272 0.0231 0.02913    0.01226 0.02646
   # 
   # Using the training set, 9 variables were selected:
   #    Cl.thickness, Cell.size, Cell.shape, Marg.adhesion, Epith.c.size...
   # 
   # During resampling, the top 5 selected variables (out of a possible 9):
   #    Bare.nuclei (100%), Bl.cromatin (100%), Cell.shape (100%), Cell.size (100%), Cl.thickness (100%)
   # 
   # On average, 9 variables were selected (min = 9, max = 9)

   ## Class of sbf_roc
   class(sbf_roc)
   # [1] "sbf"

   ## Names of elements of sbf_roc
   names(sbf_roc)
   #  [1] "pred"         "variables"    "results"      "fit"          "optVariables"
   #  [6] "call"         "control"      "resample"     "metrics"      "times"       
   # [11] "resampledCM"  "obsLevels"    "dots"        

   ## sbf_roc fit element*  
   sbf_roc$fit
   # Random Forest 
   # 
   # 683 samples
   #   9 predictor
   #   2 classes: 'benign', 'malignant' 
   # 
   # No pre-processing
   # Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times) 
   # Summary of sample sizes: 615, 614, 614, 615, 615, 615, ... 
   # Resampling results across tuning parameters:
   # 
   #   mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec       Accuracy   Kappa    
   #   2     0.9933176  0.9706566  0.9833333  0.9751492  0.9460717
   #   5     0.9920034  0.9662121  0.9791667  0.9707801  0.9363708
   #   9     0.9914825  0.9684343  0.9708333  0.9693308  0.9327662
   # 
   # ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
   # The final value used for the model was mtry = 2. 

   ##  Elements of sbf_roc fit  
   names(sbf_roc$fit)
   #  [1] "method"       "modelInfo"    "modelType"    "results"      "pred"        
   #  [6] "bestTune"     "call"         "dots"         "metric"       "control"     
   # [11] "finalModel"   "preProcess"   "trainingData" "resample"      "resampledCM" 
   # [16] "perfNames"    "maximize"     "yLimits"      "times"        "levels"      

   ## sbf_roc fit final Model
   sbf_roc$fit$finalModel

   # Call:
   #  randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry) 
   #                Type of random forest: classification
   #                      Number of trees: 500
   # No. of variables tried at each split: 2
   # 
   #         OOB estimate of  error rate: 2.34%
   # Confusion matrix:
   #           benign malignant class.error
   # benign       431        13  0.02927928
   # malignant      3       236  0.01255230

   ## sbf_roc metric
   sbf_roc$fit$metric
   # [1] "ROC"

   ## sbf_roc fit best Tune  
   sbf_roc$fit$bestTune
   #   mtry
   # 1    2
```

Does `sbf()` use `metric` argument to optimize model?  If yes, what `metric` does `sbf()` use as default? If `sbf()` uses `metric` argument, then how to set it to `ROC`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sbf` doesn't use the metric to optimize anything (unlike `rfe`); all `sbf` does is do a feature selection step before calling the model. Of course, you define the filters but there is no way to tune the filter using `sbf` so no metric is needed to guide that step.

Using `sbf(x, y, metric = "ROC")` will pass `metric = "ROC"` to whatever modeling function that you are using (and it designed to work with `train` when `caretSBF` is used. This happens because there is no `metric` argument to `sbf`:

```
> names(formals(caret:::sbf.default))
[1] "x"          "y"          "sbfControl" "..."
```

Comment: That quite convincing. But could you please throw some information on how does `sbf()` pass the argument `metric="ROC"`, `method="rf"`to `caretSBF$fit` and not any other element of `caretSBF`. How does it pass the values of `train()` arguments from `sbf()` to `train()` inside `caretSBF$fit`. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Because of the ellipsis `...` three dots in `sbf()` , we are able to provide arguments, but how does it know it should go to `train()` inside `caretSBF$fit` and not any other.